# What is the growth function and order in this code?

Tags: java, big-o, analysis

I'm trying to understand the growth function of this code.

```
 for (int count=0; count < n; count++) {
   for (int count2=1; count2 < n; count2=count2*2) {
     System.out.println(count + ", " + count2);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Well, how many times does each loop iterate?

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132331/what-is-o-and-how-do-i-calculate-it

Comment: Time complexity is  **O(nlogn)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer loop is linear since you're incrementing by one each time. The inner loop is log(n) since your upper bound would have to increase exponentially to keep up with the growth of the count2 variable therefore the entire nested iteration is nlog(n) .

Comment: That's assuming you can convert a number to a string in constant time; but the number of digits to print is also logarithmic in the size of the number. So it's actually O(n log^2 n) because of that.

Comment: @kaya3 Conversion of a number to a string is a language/computer specific aspect. By your logic, I could argue that as an integer has a maximum size the print statement would add a constant factor to the complexity and not another log. The theoretical complexity of the given code is nlog(n).

Comment: @akuzminykh That is not at all "by my logic". It only makes sense to do asymptotic analysis if we assume that the numbers involved can be arbitrarily large. There is no way to output O(log n) characters in less than O(log n) time. If you want to argue that converting a number to a string takes O(1) time because all numbers are bounded by Integer.MAX_VALUE, then the same argument says that these `for` loops iterate at most a bounded number of times therefore the whole algorithm takes O(1) time. That's clearly nonsense.

Comment: @kaya3 You are right. If i is bounded to a limit, n is bounded as well. Anyways, I need to add that there are two variables that need to be considered for conversion.

Comment: @akuzminykh Yes, there are two numbers being printed on each iteration. We can simplify the argument by just counting the digits for `count`, and then saying that `count2` can't have more than O(log n) digits because it's bounded by n. For just `count`, we can say that for half of the iterations of the inner loop, `count >= n/2` so it has O(log n) digits on those half of the iterations, and therefore an overall average of O(log n).

Comment: @kaya3 I think the overall complexity should be O(n*log(n)*2log(n)) = O(n*log^2(n)). Bravo!

Answer (score 1):

A good way to approach these problems when you're just starting to learn about growth and order is by thinking about it visually. Refer to the diagram and explanation below:

[image]

Assume n = 8 and printing is a constant time operation.

Look at the loops separately first.

The outer loop is fairly trivial:
we start with a count of 0, and increment `count` by 1 each time until we reach n = 8. Therefore, we must increment 8/1 = 8 times in order to complete the loop. Generalized to n, the loop will run for n times.

The inner loop is slightly more involved:
we start with a count of 1 and increment by multiplying 2 to `count2` until we reach n = 8. In this way, `count2` increases by a factor of 2 at each iteration and its value can be determined by 2^k where k is the number of iterations. To figure out how many iterations it will take to reach n = 8, solve 2^k = 8 or k = log2(8) = 3. Generalized to n the loop will run for log2(n) times.

Combining these two facts, the inner loop will be run for every iteration of the outer loop so all in all, it will take n * log2(n) to run. Therefore, the runtime complexity is O(nlog(n))